# Connect Xamarin Sndroid application to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin

I'm trying to create an Android app via Xamarin and I want to connect this app to a remote database in SQL Server in order to make queries. How can I do so?

Comment: The most common approach is you don't. You use a WebService to service your app requests

Comment: Also "*how can I do so*" questions are consider low quality, this not a programming problem, its just a statement of intent

Comment: Can you please tell us what did you try? It's better to provide some coding sample as well.

Comment: i've seen that there's a way to do so using restful API or by creating WCF but the examples weren't very clear so I didn't understand the criteria of doing so

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to SQL server via xamarin is not that much good idea. I strongly not recommend this. If you have to do something with database at mobile I can suggest you [SQLLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) . You can find many example how people do with this.

The best approach will be creating a WebApi to handle logic and database works and communicate via json requests to your mobile app.

This is a huge concept that can not be easily expalin as a answer here. I suggest you to split your works by creating your web api and mobile ui at diffrent solutions.

- Create a web api with .net core
- Create your mobile app
- Send your request from one platfrm to other one via json.

Anyway If you want to see a real world example to handle similiar goals as your have a look to this [sample](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) that created by Microsoft.